# c# many-to-many relationship code first without fluent API

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6, code-first

I'm trying to understand Entity Framework Code First.

Is it possible to configure a many-to-many relationship without using fluent API but just DataAnnotation?
For example in [this tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) I don't understand if the two examples are the same thing but done in different ways or if they have to exist together.

- If they are different ways for the same thing, what is actually the difference?
- And if they have to coexist, what is the API "part" doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you are right.

This paragraph:

> **Configure Many-to-Many relationship using DataAnnotation:**
>
> Student class should have a collection navigation property for Course, and Course should have a collection navigation property for student,

is wrong. Because the many-to-many relationship in the sample code in created automatically by convention when you add a collection in each class. The only data annotation that is used is `Required` attribute which is not implied in the many-to-many relationship.

BTW the section about "Configure Many-to-Many relationship using Fluent API" is correct but in their sample code they use it only put a custom name to the foreign key in the join table instead of letting Code First generating it. Foreing key renaming can be done too with Data Annotation by using `ForeignKey` attribute.

Comment: What is the `HashSet` in Course constructor? I've seen examples that use this notation for both side of the ralationship, but here it's using it just inside Course.

Comment: If you have enabled Lazy Loading and enabled Proxy you dont need to put those lines into the constructors. These two configurations are enabled by default by Code First. 
The initialization into the constructor avoid developper to instantiate the collection somewhere in your code when you create a new instance of Course or Student. Globally when you instantiate a Course automatticlly the constructor instantiate the collection of Student then you can do just after course.Students.Add without course.Students = new Hashset<Student>() because the constructor already did it for you.

Comment: they are enabled by default. To take advantage of that the only thing you need to take care is that all your properties scalar, navigational and collection properties must be declared as virtual and have a getter and setter. If you do that the instantiation into the constructor is no more needed.

Answer (score 1):

They're two different ways of configuring the database.  They can coexist, but they don't have to; you can use just one or the other.  If you do use both, the Fluent API takes precedence over the data annotations, but the data annotations still take precedence over the default conventions.

The difference is that API allows a more exacting degree of control, in exchange for being (arguably) more complicated.  The example you linked does show two different ways of accomplishing effectively the same thing, and you could use one or the other if you wanted to create that specific many-to-many relationship.  But the API method would be more configurable if you wanted to do something odd with that CourseStudents (or StudentCourse) table, while the annotation method would be more limited but is easier to read at a glance if you don't need the extra functionality.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build a really simple wpf application. So, since API seems to be more difficult, I think I'll use Data Annotation.